# How to get dynamic element to fire a drop down Jquery/Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to get a dynamic dropdown to occur on objects from the DB. Each new object adds a new div to the DOM.

Currently, I've got it kind of working...But the issue is the alert firing is firing 3x because there are 3 Nodes of this type. If there were 9 Nodes, it would probably fire 9 times.

Here's my code.

html.erb:

```
    <div class="exercise-card col-xs-12" id="<%=exercise.id%>" data-html="true">
    <div class="control-panel col-xs-12">
        <%=link_to "", new_user_workout_exercise_round_path(current_user, @workout, exercise), class: "fa fa-plus-circle pull-right", data: {toggle: "tooltip", placement: "bottom"}, title: "Add Set" %><i class="fa fa-play-circle pull-right" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Play <%= exercise.exercise_name %> Video" data-html="true"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">
        <h3 class="exercise-name"><%= exercise.exercise_name %></h3>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">
        <span class="medium-text">
            <%= exercise.num_of_sets %> Sets •
            <%= exercise.rep_range %> Reps •
            <%= exercise.rest_period %> Rest
        </span>
    </div>
    <div id="card-expand" data-html="true">
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
<script>


$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.exercise-card').click(function(e) {
    var currentId = $(this).attr('id');
    alert("#"+currentId)
  });
});
</script>
```

What i'm hoping will happen is in the div id#card-expand there will be dynamic content specific to that card that will drop down on a particular card that is clicked.

Fairly new to JS. Thanks for your help.

EDITs:

```
<div class="exercise_cards col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
<div class="exercise-card col-xs-12" id="<%=exercise.id%>" data-html="true">
    <div class="control-panel col-xs-12">
        <%=link_to "", new_user_workout_exercise_round_path(current_user, @workout, exercise), class: "fa fa-plus-circle pull-right", data: {toggle: "tooltip", placement: "bottom"}, title: "Add Set" %><i class="fa fa-play-circle pull-right" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Play <%= exercise.exercise_name %> Video" data-html="true"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">
        <h3 class="exercise-name"><%= exercise.exercise_name %></h3>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">
        <span class="medium-text">
            <%= exercise.num_of_sets %> Sets •
            <%= exercise.rep_range %> Reps •
            <%= exercise.rest_period %> Rest
        </span>
    </div>
    <div id="card-expand-<%=exercise.id%>" data-html="true" style="display: none;">
        <h3><%= exercise.exercise_name%></h3>
        <br class="clr" /><hr /><hr /><hr />
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<script>


 $(document).ready(function() {
   $('.exercise-card').off().click(function(e) {
    var currentId = $(this).attr('id');
      $('#card-expand-'+currentId).toggle()
   });
 });
</script>
```

Comment: You binding click event for every element that has `.exercise-car` class name and its mean every time "one" of these element be clicked, trigger an alert. It's weird to get 3x alert. Could you provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: @ColinCline Looks like i actually figured it out while waiting for someone to come rescue me. haha Here's the code. Does this make sense? who knows maybe it's another bug waiting to happen. But it seems to be working right.

Comment: Added as Edits @ColinCline

Comment: `off()` method removes all event handlers that you set in this element with `on()` method and if this solved your problem, means you bind an `on()` event handler to this class name that make `alert` function trigger many times based on that bind (or your html make it act like this because you are using ruby that i don't have too much knowledge about that)